# Find the name of SQL Server database which contains a user defined function

Tags: sql-server, database, function, find

I am having many databases in my SQL object explorer. I found some function being called in code but not sure from which database it is trying to find it. Is there any way to get the name of database which contains function with that name?

Expecting some query which will return me the name of database by taking name of function as input

Comment: The database will either be specified `databaseName.schema.Function()` or it will be in whichever database the code is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Just posting it incase someone else needs it:

```
SELECT name DatabaseName
FROM sys.databases
WHERE OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.nameofyourfunction', 'FN') IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That might not be the answer because this finds in which database the function is defined, it can be called from anywhere else

Comment: @siggemannen If I read the OP correctly, and I might not be, they want to find out where the function lives, so they can call it with a three-part name, not where it is currently being called _from_. As in, the current code just says `function()` with no database qualifier, and they want to fix the code. But they need to know where the function is, first. This answer will do that (though it may come up with more than one answer).

Comment: @Stuckat1337 his wording can go either way I would say :)